# Using RPX or similar openID selector in other languages than English

Tags: openid, translation, rpx

When you login to Stackoverflow you see a button with the openID logo between the text input field and the submit button.

When you click this button you get a dropdown with the main openID providers. This is an integrated 3rd party service called 'ID selector' which has been deprecated in favour of it's successor RPX ([rpxnow.com](http://rpxnow.com)). RPX even gives the user the possibility to login with existing Facebook, AOL, Google, etc. accounts.

This is an **excellent service** but I need it in *German* and it seems it's only available in *English*.

Has anyone encountered this problem and can share thoughts? Or has anyone even solved it?
It would be a pitty if I couldn't use this great service just because there is no way to translate (@PhiLho: see*) these few strings in the js popup...

**EDIT**: *as a programming term: fetch, translate, return... like translate();

The question is, can I get the strings out and inject my translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the kind word on RPX.  Translations are on the shortterm roadmap.

UPDATE: Translations have been implemented.

Comment: I recently did a new translation and they included it quickly. Now my entire website is localized. Kudos to RPX team.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out DotNetOpenID which I started incorporating in [Stacked](http://stacked-ra.ajax.org) yesterday in fact. I haven't gotten to play much around with it, and obviously I don't care about anything else then English (yet at least) but it seems promising... :)